# aSmack + Android : MultiUserChat class; getMembers, getModerators, etc not working?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

i'm using aSmack (Smack port for Android) to connect to and communicate with an XMPP server (Openfire 3.7.1).  i can get multi user chat to work as far as sending messages with the MultiUserChat class.  however, calling any method that lists the occupants of the room fails.  relevant code:

```
setDefaultConnection();
if(connection!=null) {
    mMuc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "hermitage_recycling@conference.jmartinw7");
    try {
        mMuc.join("chester");
        mMuc.getModerators();         //line 71
        ArrayList<Affiliate> dudes = new ArrayList<Affiliate>(mMuc.getMembers());
        Iterator<Affiliate> iter = dudes.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Affiliate dude = iter.next();
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), dude.getNick());
        }
    } catch(XMPPException xmppe) {
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "MUC error: "+xmppe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
07-10 13:38:56.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getOccupants(MultiUserChat.java:1797)
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getModerators(MultiUserChat.java:1761)
    at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient$1.onClick(XMPPClient.java:71)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
```

is there something wrong with the library or am i doing something wrong?  getOccupants() seems to work.

MultiUserChat example and javadocs:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html

aSmack:
http://code.google.com/p/asmack/
http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=72

Comment: u got any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [README](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/README.markdown) of [aSmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/) and follow the instructions about the ProviderManager.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is being caused by a failure for asmack to load the smack.providers file which tells asmack which classes to load. If you read the README it describes how to load the smack.providers file into asmack(Thanks Flow). You need to do this before starting any XMPP activity.

Try https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack, as the version you are working off has not been updated in 2 years.

Comment: problem persists after switching to version 7 (latest jar).

Comment: @moonlightcheese Did you read the [README](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/README.markdown) and follow the instructions about the ProviderManager?

Comment: @Flow if you want cred, provide this as an answer so i can accept it.  thanks, this solved it.